# Recovery mode or boot USB for an Apple iMac 20" A1224 (2009)

Tags: macos, recovery

Recently found an Apple iMac 20" A1224 (2009) on the side of the road and want to wipe and reinstall (don't know former user password).

I'm using a regular wireless keyboard (is this the problem?) and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not respond. I have tried a few other options no luck!

I have no idea what os is running but, I assume it's probably El captain. Please help I want to turn this into a retro arcade for my son.

Comment: Try using a wired keyboard. That should work. Wireless keyboards _might_ work but a wired keyboard would definitely work.